# Уникальность URL

Tags: url

Нужно привести URL к виду, в котором можно оценивать равенство. Интересуют только сами URL, то, что по ним может отдаваться разный контент - отставим в сторону. Протоколы не учитываем. Якоря в ajax-страницах тоже. Пока вырисовывается:

```
sub unify_url
{
  my ( $url ) = @_;

  # http://test.com/#anchor => //test.com/
  my $uu = URI->new($url)->opaque();

  # у кого-то '+', у кого-то '%20'...
  $uu = uri_unescape($uu);

  $uu =~ s|/+$||;

  $uu;
}
```

Ничего не упустил?

Comment: Может, еще стоит имя домена привести к одному регистру и отрезать правый PATH_SEPARATOR.

ps. Прошу прощения, это Perl?

Comment: Ну а еще GET параметры могут быть попутаны местами. Есть смысл распарсить их, отсортировать как-то и прилепить обратно.

Comment: @Bars, про мешанину в GET - да, красивая путаница может выйти :) Но на это пока забиваем. Регистр само собой, PATH_SEPARATOR отрезается в последней строчке. Да, это Perl, но принцип-то везде одинаковый будет :)

Comment: Ну тогда еще можно отделить GET параметры, отрезать PATH_SEPARATOR, и прилепить GET обратно — для такого случая:

    ://somehost.com/path/to/?file_pointer=that/

Вроде все. Про путаницу с GET не забудь потом :)

Comment: @Bars, вот спасибо! Про такие случаи "думал, но забыл" :)


`test.com?a=b`

vs

`test.com/?a=b`